# Run node.js application in debug with supervisor

Tags: node.js, node-supervisor

I am using [supervisor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor) to auto-reload my node.js, e.g.

```
supervisor -w . app.js
```

However I can't work out how to get supervisor to run the node.js process in debug, e.g. the equivalent to

```
node --debug app.coffee
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Supervisor link broken. The webpage displays "Posterous Spaces is no longer available"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution will work for *nix:

Go to `/usr/local/bin` or any other directory in your $PATH

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
```

Create an executable script (say, node-debug) with the following contents

```
#!/bin/bash
node --debug $@
```

To make it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/node-debug
```

Now you can run supervisor like this:

```
$ supervisor -x node-debug script.js
```

P.S.: To round it up:

```
su
echo '#!/bin/bash
node --debug $@' > /usr/local/bin/node-debug
chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/node-debug
```

Comment: This way I get `debugger listening on port 5858 Failed to open socket on port 5858, waiting 1000 ms before retrying` while manual `node --debug` works fine.

Answer (score 28):

This also works (and you don't need a separate bash script):

```
supervisor -- --debug app.js
supervisor -- --debug=7070 app.js
```

Comment: Yes this works so simply, and also with the "advanced" inspector too, e.g. for running Express: `DEBUG=myapp:* supervisor -- --inspect bin/www`.  I got event-errors trying to use the -x parameter, but this alternative parameter format works.

Answer (score 4):

From the [CoffeeScript site](http://coffeescript.org) :

> --nodejs The node executable has some useful options you can set, such as
>   --debug, --debug-brk and --max-stack-size. Use this flag to forward options directly to Node.js.

I tried this and it worked:

supervisor -- --nodejs --debug app.coffee

You can add other arguments like this:

supervisor -w . -n error -- --nodejs --debug app.coffee

Answer (score 3):

<strike>[node-dev](http://fgnass.posterous.com/nodejs-supervisor)</strike>

[node-dev on Github](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev)

> "All arguments are passed on to the child-process. node-dev --debug server.js will debug your application, not the supervisor itself."

Create a "test.js" node.js script in $HOME/nodetest

First terminal (run node in debug mode, debug will listen on the port 5858, node-dev will reload changed files):

```
    cd $HOME/nodetest
    npm install node-dev
    node_modules/.bin/node-dev --debug test.js
```

Second terminal (start web inspector for a WebKit based browser, inspector connects to the port 5858 of the debugger and listens on the port 8080):

```
    cd $HOME/nodetest
    npm install node-inspector
    node_modules/.bin/node-inspector
```

Open this URL in a WebKit based browser (Chrome, Safari, etc.):

```
    http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858
```

Click on "Scripts" and set breakpoints in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-x` flag as documented on the [`node-supervisor` github page](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)

`supervisor -w . -x 'node --debug' app.js`

but that won't work with coffeescript so you have to use

`supervisor -w . -x 'coffee --debug' app.js`

Comment: tried that but it goes into an infinite loop with DEBUG: Starting child process with 'coffee --debug app.coffee'
DEBUG: execvp(): No such file or directory

Comment: @JamesHollingworth I think it was too much to expect `coffee --debug` to just work :P