# Starting node server with increased memory

Tags: node.js

On server startup (using command `supervisor ./bin/www`) I'm exporting a huge data from mongodb to redis and getting an error:

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`

However, if I start the command using `node --max-old-space-size=4076 ./bin/www` it works fine.

How to configure `supervisor` to start node with 4gb memory?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7482257/2308005 maybe helps

Comment: Hi medet, thank you for your response. I tried to, with the help of the link you provided , run with the command like this `supervisor -w . -x node --max-old-space-size=4076 ./bin/www`. but still throwing same error

Comment: Thank you middaparka for editing my question

Comment: Any one please help me out

Comment: Hi Medet, can you please help me out in this